# How to apply background color to checkbox using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for a few hours now without any luck. Seems like everyone uses a background image to solve their problem, and I only want to use a color so the solution scales better without extra CSS needed for mobile devices.

I almost have a working solution, but 1) the "checkbox" is not clickable like the rest of the label; 2) I just can't seem to find any way to add space between the label and the "checkbox" without altering the HTML (something that I prefer not to do, but will try if there's no workable CSS-only or JQuery solution).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="edit-field-school-education-und" class="form-checkboxes">
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-school-education-und-28">
        <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-school-education-und-28" name="field_school_education[und][28]" value="28" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-school-education-und-28">Evening Classes &amp; Distance Learning </label>
    </div>
     ......  Repeated for several checkboxes   .......
</div>
```

Here's my CSS so far:

```
.form-checkbox {display:none}
.form-checkbox + label:before {content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0"; height: 19px; width: 19px; border: 1px  solid black; cursor:pointer; }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {background-color: #34c1ce;}
```

I prefer a CSS3 solution, but would be okay with a **generic** HTML or JS solution. I can't have a solution based on IDs etc. since the checkbox list may grow at any time. However, I could probably figure out a way to output a div with the same label text.

Comment: The checkbox element, as well as many other input types, are controlled by the browser's own stylesheet. They are set with the !important declaration and cannot be changed by any other CSS. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade

You will probably have to use JS.

@spy-killer's link looks cool too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant set a background color to a checkbox it is rendered depending on the browser not the css, But you could set a background image here is a handy tutorial

http://www.whatstyle.net/articles/18/pretty_form_controls_with_css

Comment: This solution uses images, which I said I'm not looking to use.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to create your own checkboxes with buttons and JavaScript or use a JavaScript UI. This however means that it doesn't work if JavaScript isn't enabled so you may wish to create a fallback (have a checkbox shown by default and use JS to switch it out with the custom one).

Comment: That sounds interesting...do you have an example you can link to?

Comment: This http://jqueryui.com/ is an easy way to implement stylable checkboxes but requires JS to be enabled. I don't currently have an example of custom UI though.

Comment: Okay thanks...I'll research this some more. I assume the JS will need to also check the checkbox when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes. Just put a checkbox in the button element then set `visibility:hidden` so it isn't shown. You can then use JavaScript to check and uncheck the input behind the scenes while changing the class/styles of the button element. The checkbox should correctly pass the data when the form is submitted.

You should also consider alternate styles to allow the checkbox to be shown if JS is disabled.

Comment: Thanks I will check this out as a possibility.